# Sort Dictionary by numerical key value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Dictionary called `lookupTable`

Inside `lookupTable` I have values

```
{1:"word", 2:"word", 3:"word" etc...}
```

I want to print it out in numerical order (by the key)

I have tried to find a solution. I can only get it to print like this:

> 1:"word"
>
> 11:"word"
>
> 2:"Word"
>
> 22:"Word"

Help?

Comment: Post your solution and maybe we can tell you what's wrong.

Comment: if your dictionary has this format `sorted(d.items())` will work like you want. post the relevant portion of your code, or we cannot help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this. I assumed the your dictionary is called **lookupTable** so this is jut an explanatory example.

```
keyList = lookupTable.keys()
orderedKeyList = keyList.sort()

for key in orderedKeyList:
    print (str(key) + " " + dictionary[key])
```